# Remove column if contains partial string

Tags: r, dataframe

This seems simple enough but I could not find a solution on this site. I would simply like to remove all columns from a dataframe if they contain a particular partial string match of "gs://". The table has 100's of columns and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Replace image in your question with its text and use its field separator.

Comment: In the future, please post copy-pasteable data using `dput()`, [not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17303805). See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this example data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c("gs://red", "orange"), 
  y = c("yellow", "gs://green"), 
  z = c("blue", "indigo")
)

dat
#          x          y      z
# 1 gs://red     yellow   blue
# 2   orange gs://green indigo
```

Index the dataframe using `grepl()`:

```r
dat[!sapply(dat, \(x) any(grepl("gs://", x)))]
#        z
# 1   blue
# 2 indigo
```

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I see, thank you! Changed to a safer approach using `sapply()`.

Comment: I like the other approach! Why wouldn't it find the character "c"?

Comment: The problem is that it would find `"c"`s even if not present in your data. This is because `grepl()` coerces the dataframe using `as.character()`, which (to my surprise) yields `"c(\"gs://red\", \"orange\")"   "c(\"yellow\", \"gs://green\")" "c(\"blue\", \"indigo\")"`.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively with `dplyr::select_if`

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% select_if(~!any(str_detect(.,'gs://')))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
       z
1   blue
2 indigo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `select` with `where`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   select(where(~ all(str_detect(.x, fixed("gs://"), negate = TRUE))))
```

-output

```
       z
1   blue
2 indigo
```